# Monitor ssh on non-default port with Nagios

Tags: linux, ssh, monitoring, port, nagios

I just deployed Nagios on a Gentoo server and everything is fine except ssh, which it marks as "CRITICAL" because it's refusing connections. But that's because it's running on a port different from the default 22. How do I change it so that it monitors the right port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
host:~$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ssh --help
check_ssh v1991 (nagios-plugins 1.4.12)
Copyright (c) 1999 Remi Paulmier <remi@sinfomic.fr>
Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Nagios Plugin Development Team
        <nagiosplug-devel@lists.sourceforge.net>

Try to connect to an SSH server at specified server and port


Usage:check_ssh [-46] [-t <timeout>] [-r <remote version>] [-p <port>] <host>
```

does this answer your question? -p parameter lets you specify the port, make custom check in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg and put there:

```
command[check_remote_ssh]= /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ssh -p 1234 some.host
```

Comment: It worked! In my case it was the local `check_ssh` in `/etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg`. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 15):

In ssh pluging config /etc/nagios-plugins/config/ssh.cfg, there an alias named check_ssh_port.
if it not existe you may define it like above:

```
$ cat >> /etc/nagios-plugins/config/ssh.cfg
define command{
        command_name    check_ssh_port
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ssh -p '$ARG1$' '$HOSTADDRESS$'
        }
```

in the service file /etc/nagios3/conf.d/services_nagios2.cfg, define you ssh service to monitor like this:

```
define service {
        hostgroup_name                  ssh2-servers
        service_description             SSH2
        check_command                   check_ssh_port!12000!server
        use                             generic-service
        notification_interval           240 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}
```

replace 12000 by you default ssh port and server by your target.

Comment: +1 well written for the latest version of nagios (at this time)

Answer (score 7):

As none of the solutions above worked for me, I'll post this small variation.

This definition is the default one (e.g.: `localhost.cfg`) with the only addition of the -p option and the space in between.

I guess it's a hybrid version of two of the solutions given.

It works on Nagios Core 4 with nagios-plugins 2.1.1

```
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       localhost
        service_description             SSH
        check_command                   check_ssh!-p 12345
        notifications_enabled           1
        }
```

Comment: It can also be changed/configured in Nagios4 web interface: **System** --> **Configuration**, then appending the exclamation mark and commandline options `check_ssh!-p 123456`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can also define the second parameter, "server", in the host_name parameter this way:

```
    define host{
        use                     generic-host            ; Name of host template to use
        host_name               host
        alias                   host
        address                 92.193.170.124
}


# Define a service to check if ssh services are running
define service {
        use                     generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name               host
        service_description     SSH Port 4959
        check_command           check_ssh_port!4959
        notification_interval   0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}
```

So, if the address of the host changes, you only have to modify this parameter once, for all services defined for this host.

Answer (score 0):

```
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               localhost
        service_description     SSH
        check_command           check_ssh!-p 9898
        }
```

working properly you can try it.